# Relationship between Abelian category and Grothendieck topology

Tags: category-theory, homology-cohomology

[Grothendieck topology wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_topology) says "it becomes possible to define sheaves on a category and their cohomology." On the otherhand, [abelian category wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_category) says "The theory originated in an effort to unify several cohomology theories by Alexander Grothendieck and independently in the slightly earlier work of David Buchsbaum." It seems that these two notion is intended for same purpose(i.e. cohomology theory). Is there a relationship between these two notion? I'd appreciate if you could answer the question.

Comment: The very first thing one does when one has a Grothendieck topology on a category is to construct another category which is an Abelian one — its category of sheaves (or preserves), and the geometry of the topology is studied using invariants that take values in the abelian category.

Comment: That is, the notion of cohomology is defined by an abelian category, then one can construct from a site(a category with a grothendieck topology) its category of sheaves which is the abelian category, is this right? However I recently learn a cech cohomology, but it seems that it is based in the concept of a site but not in an abelian category. I'm confused right now.

Comment: For example, is the term "cohomology" like the term "natural" before a natural transformation is developed? It was already known that if $K$ is a field, then for every vector space $V$ over $K$ we have a "natural" injective linear map $V$ $\rightarrow$ $V^{**}$. However, historically, I think that the term "natural" wasn't strictly defined until natural transformation is defined.

Comment: I understand as below: Buchsbaum and Grothendieck would have liked to unify cohomology theory using abelian category, but they couldn't do that. As a result, cech cohomology where use only the concept of a site, and so on remain. So, I think the answer of my question is: No relationship has been found _yet_.

Comment: Oh well. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thank you for your comments!